# Pandas merging monthly data from one dataframe with daily data in another

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file (say A.csv) with an index from 1980-01-01 to 2018-02-28 (increased by a day) and one data column (say everyday's stock price).

I have another csv file  (say B.csv) with an index from 1980-01 to 2018-02 (increased by a month) and one data column (say monthly trade balance).

In such case, how do merge B.csv to A.csv (by maintaining daily index)?
i.e., daily index + one column for daily stock price + another column for monthly trade balance (I need to expand monthly trade balance to daily trade balance by maintaining the same trade balance values for each days in a month).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `pandas`.

One way to do this is to convert both date columns to `datetime` objects, and use `pd.Series.map` to perform the mapping from one table to the other.

Since day is not specified for your monthly data, for our mapping we normalise to the first day of the month.

```
import pandas as pd

# first read in the 2 tables into dataframes
# df_daily = pd.read_csv('daily.csv')
# df_monthly = pd.read_csv('monthly.csv')

df_daily = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['1980-01-01', '1980-01-02', '1980-01-03'],
                         'Value': [1, 2, 3]})

df_monthly = pd.DataFrame({'Month': ['1979-12', '1980-01', '1980-03'],
                           'Value': [100, 200, 300]})

# convert to datetime objects
df_daily['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_daily['Date'])
df_monthly['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df_monthly['Month']+'-01')

# perform mapping after normalising to first day of month
df_daily['MonthValue'] = df_daily['Date'].map(lambda x: x.replace(day=1))\
                                         .map(df_monthly.set_index('Month')['Value'])

#         Date  Value  MonthValue
# 0 1980-01-01      1         200
# 1 1980-01-02      2         200
# 2 1980-01-03      3         200
```

Comment: BTW, one more question....how about the case that columns 'Date' in df_daily and 'Month' in df_monthly are not the values but the indexes?

Comment: You can elevate `df_daily` index to column or use `pd.Series(df_daily.index).map(...)`. For `df_monthly` you don't need set the index to Month explicitly.